# What does this mean: data-component-bound="true"?

Tags: html, css

What does data-component-bound="true" mean?

I've found this within a collapsed  element but adjusting the value doesn't do anything. I've tried looking for the attribute "data-component-bound" on Stack Overflow and on Google but it points to a limited set of various jquery articles which are over my head and which take it for granted.

**[edit post some answers]**

Ahh, I see now that i should have been searching for "data-" to solve this. In so doing, I found this useful article which could help the next person: http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/

Comment: You can make up any `data-` attribute you like. Your example would depend on who wrote the code and what they needed it for. There is no generic answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data-` attributes are extensible: the author of the code can make up any data attribute they like. In this case, from a quick look, it seems it is used for the internal workings of websites to know when the 'component' (i.e. DOM element) is 'bound' to something - an event, an interaction, etc.

In general, `data-` attributes are used for that: data. They store any data, so are often used to substitute non-standard attributes that would otherwise flag up in a validator.

Answer (score 3):

HTML data attributes allow you to set custom data for an element. The meaning of `data-component-bound` is determined by your code or some css or javascript framework that you might be using.

Search the codebase for 'component-bound' to see if it's being used. If you don't find anything, Google it to see if it's a popular attribute from some framework. If it's not, then you're safe to remove it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes